# How do I make an infinite for loop in Python (without using a while loop)?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there way to write an infinite for loop in Python?

```
for t in range(0,10):
    if(t == 9): t= 0 # will this set t to 0 and launch infinite loop? No!
    print(t)
```

Generally speaking, is there way to write infinite pythonic for loop like in java without using a while loop?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you ask this question?

Comment: @joelgoldstick, i m making slides for high schools about python, i made one about while infinite loop and got curious - is there way to do infinite loop in python, so that's why asking

Comment: I 'm curious to why `for i in range(0, 1, -1) : print("Hello")` too doesn't work?

Answer (score 8):

The itertools.repeat function will return an object endlessly, so you could loop over that:

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.repeat(1):
    pass
```

Answer (score 6):

To iterate over an iterable over and over again, you would use `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle
for t in cycle(range(0, 4)):
    print(t)
```

This will print the following output:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create your own infinite generator with `cycle`

```
from itertools import cycle

gen = cycle([0])

for elt in gen:
    # do stuff
```

or basically use `itertools.count()`:

```
for elt in itertools.count():
    # do stuff
```

Comment: What do you mean by `cycle(_)` (the underscore)?

Comment: it's a convention for throwaway variables

Comment: Yes, but it is not assigned in your example. Running that, you will get a `NameError: name '_' is not defined`.

Comment: By default, it is assigned to '' in my ipython console... You're right thx !

Comment: In interactive consoles it has a different meaning usually, there it represents the result of the last operation.

Comment: sure, but at first launch it is set to '', probably somewhere in my ipython config file...

Comment: And for just repeating the same value over and over again, you use `repeat`. You only use `cycle` when you want to repeatedly iterate over an iterable object like a list.

Answer (score -7):

Just pass could help with forever true value.

```
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: the question is "without using a while loop"